# socketRead0 implementation, and communication between JDBC and glibc

Tags: java, linux, jdbc, glibc

As per my understanding `java.net` talkes with `glibc`.
I want to know in Java JDBC source, which method is talking with `glibc` socket methods for implementing socket in Java.

And where can I get the definition of `socketRead0`

Answer (score 0):

It isn't in the JDBC source code at all.

It is in the `java.net` source code, and its native JNI past, and the JVM library that supports it. All over the place. Keep looking.

Why do you think you need to know? You don't.

Answer (score 0):

JDBC is an interface.

The actual code implemented by a JDBC provider. Each provider depending on there background and what was flavor of the month when they first implemented thier JDBC library will probably be using a different method.

Of the two I am most familiar with SQLITE and DB2, the sqlite implementation just calls the sqlite C api. The DB2 implementation makes extensive use of java asynchronous IO libraries as well as the standard JAVA sockets libraries.